# Making the "Calling method" wait for the "Return" of data

Tags: java, swing, methods, callback, actionlistener

I have 2 classes, one class is a `JFrame` (**MainUIHolder.java**) and the other class is a `JDialog` (**EditValuationsDialog.java**). `MainUIHolder` can call `EditValuationsDialog` on button click event.

Once `EditValuationsDialog` is open, user can enter data in its fields and press its "Add" button. OK, here is the issue now. Once the user press the "Add" button, the `EditValuationsDialog` should inform that to the `MainUIHolder`.

Below is the code.

**MainUIHolder**

```
  Action edit = new AbstractAction()
    {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
              JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
              int rowNum = Integer.valueOf(e.getActionCommand());
              Object valueAt = table.getModel().getValueAt(rowNum, 0);

              EditValuationsDialog edit = new EditValuationsDialog(null,true);
              edit.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
              edit.setTitle("Edit Valuations");
              edit.setClientName(portfolioViewClientName.getText());
edit.setPortfolioType(portfolioViewInvestmentTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
              edit.setPortfolioId(id);
                                                                          edit.setOngoingValuationsId(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(valueAt)));
              edit.setLocationRelativeTo(table);
               edit.setVisible(true);

               //CATCH THE CALL FROM EditValuationsDialog HERE!!!!//

             }
  };
```

**EditValuationsDialog**

```
//Action Listeners
    private class AddBtnAction implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
           if(someCondition)
           {
              return String / int to MainUIHolder (See where I want to catch it in MainUIHolder)
           }
          else
          {
            do nothing
          }

        }
    }
```

In my code I have indicated from where the call to `MainUIHolder` should be generated and in what place I must catch that call in `MainUIHolder`. How can I do this call back work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You could...

Add a `static` method to `EditValuationsDialog` that shows the dialog, evaluates the results and returns the value you are expecting...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    int result = EditValuationsDialog.showDialog();
}

public class EditValuationsDialog ... {
    //...
    private int result = -1;
    //...
    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    //...
    public static int showDialog(Component source, int rowNum, Object valueAt) {

        EditValuationsDialog edit = null;
        Window parent = SwingUtilities.windowFor(source);
        if (parent instanceof Frame) {
            edit = new EditValuationsDialog((Frame)parent,true);
        } else if (parent instanceof Dialog) {
            edit = new EditValuationsDialog((Dialog)parent,true);
        } else {
            edit = new EditValuationsDialog(null,true);
        }

        edit.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        edit.setTitle("Edit Valuations");
        edit.setClientName(portfolioViewClientName.getText());
        edit.setPortfolioType(portfolioViewInvestmentTypeCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
        edit.setPortfolioId(id);
        edit.setOngoingValuationsId(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(valueAt)));
        edit.setLocationRelativeTo(source);
        edit.setVisible(true);

        return edit.getResult();
    }
    //...
    private class AddBtnAction implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(someCondition)
            {
                result = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                result = 1;
            }
            EditValuationsDialog.this.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

## Or you could...

Simply evaluate the results of `getResult()` from the above example directly...

*Side note:* Because I don't like extending from top level containers like `JDialog`, I tend to create some of my panels/components with `static` `showDialog` methods, thing something along the lines of a login panel for example.  It means I could re-use the panel else where, but provides me with the convenience of been able to popup a dialog when I need to.  I've also used `JOptionPane` from time to time to show these panels, but it depends on the complexity of the available actions...

Comment: Not clear about the answer. Apart from that, `return edit.getResult();` sections seems to return value as soon as the dialog is displayed, not minding whether the user clicked the button or not.

Comment: @Sniper `new EditValuationsDialog(null,true);` makes the dialog modal, so until it is closed, it will block at the `setVisible` call...this means, that the `AddBtnAction` `ActionListener` can set the state of the `result` field and `dispose` of the dialog, which will unblock the `setVisible` call and return the result...

Comment: Have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: ahh,got that. However your `showDialog` method cannot stay inside of `EditValuationsDialog`. Because all the `set` methods data are available in `MainUIHolder` and he is the one who should provide these to `EditValuationsDialog `

Comment: @Sniper Updated the example a little, so you need to pass some values to the `showDialog` method ... but all I have is code snippets to go by so I have no idea what and where things are...

Comment: @Sniper You could also use a "builder" pattern to build the dialog...`new EditValuationsDialogBuilder().setSource(table).setRow(rowNum).setValue(valueAt).setWhatEverOtherParameters(...).build()`, the intention of which would be to return an instance of `EditValuationsDialog` which was primed with the details you passed to the builder, then you could just have a method, like `showDialog` or `getResult`, which actually showed the dialog and returned the value of `result` after it was closed...

Answer (score 2):

Make the dialog modal (`setModal(true)`). Then the code after `dialog.setVisible(true)` is executed after the dialog is closed.

BTW it's better to pass the `MainUIHolder` `JFrame` instance as parent of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an interface to the EditValuationsDialog something like this:

```
Interface EditValuationsDialogInterface {
public void onAddClicked(addedVlue);

}
```

and then add it as such:

```
edit.setOnAddButtonCallback(new EditValuationsDialogInterface () {

@Override
onAddClicked(addedVlue){
//DO SOMETHING
}
});
```

in your EditValuationsDialog's add button onclick call add this:

```
onAddButtonClickedCallback.onAddClicked(retunrValue);
```

This allows you to have a direct link back to the original calling class.